# Error importing java.util.stream.Stream in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using Java JDK version 1.8.0_60-b27 for both Netbeans and Android Studio. I could not import `java.util.function.Consumer` and `java.util.stream.Stream` packages in my Android Studio project. But I can import the same in my Netbeans Project. What is the reason?

Comment: do you know that Android Studio support natively only java until 1.7?

Answer (score 1):

In Google I/O 2016, they announced that Android now supports some features of Java 8, but not all the features.

Features like : 
- Default and static interface methods 
- Lambda expressions (also available on API level 23 and lower) 
- Repeatable annotations 
- Method References (also available on API level 23 and lower) 
- Type Annotations (also available on API level 23 and lower)

Additionally, the following Java 8 language APIs are also available:

**Reflection and language-related APIs:** 
java.lang.FunctionalInterface java.lang.annotation.Repeatable java.lang.reflect.Method.isDefault() 
and Reflection APIs associated with repeatable annotations, such as AnnotatedElement.getAnnotationsByType(Class) Utility APIs: java.util.function java.util.stream

All what you should do is to use the new jack compiler, to do this you have just to add this to your gradle file build.gradle "module:app":

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

**Refrences** 
https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B08iLAtS3AQ&feature=youtu.be&t=28m14s

Answer (score 0):

Android only supports Java 7. Because of this you cannot use the Java Stream API introduced with Java 8. There exist some backports for this features, like

https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API for Streams

or

https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda for Lambda-Expressions.

Comment: oh thanx for your answer

Comment: @Vignesh Note that for Java 8 streams there is also [streamsupport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/streamsupport/) which is much closer to Java 8 Stream syntax and functionality than the [Lightweight-Stream-API](https://github.com/aNNiMON/Lightweight-Stream-API). For example, it also provides parallel streams.